# Idris simple proof with lists

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I am trying to prove some simple things with idris but I am failing miserably. Here is my code

```
module MyReverse
%hide reverse
%default total

reverse : List a -> List a
reverse [] = []
reverse (x :: xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]

listEmptyAppend : (l : List a) -> [] ++ l = l
listEmptyAppend [] = Refl
listEmptyAppend (x :: xs) = Refl
listAppendEmpty : (l : List a) -> l ++ [] = l
listAppendEmpty [] = Refl
listAppendEmpty (x :: xs) = rewrite listAppendEmpty xs in Refl

list_append_eq : (l, l1, l2 : List a) -> l ++ l1 = l ++ l2 -> l1 = l2
list_append_eq l [] [] prf = Refl
list_append_eq l [] (x :: xs) prf = ?list_append_eq_rhs_1
list_append_eq l (x :: xs) [] prf = ?list_append_eq_rhs_2
list_append_eq l (x :: xs) (y :: ys) prf = ?list_append_eq_rhs_3
```

The goal for `?list_append_eq_rhs_1` is (after a couple of `intro'`s)

```
----------              Assumptions:              ----------
 a : Type
 l : List a
 x : a
 xs : List a
 prf : l ++ [] = l ++ x :: xs
----------                 Goal:                  ----------
{hole0} : [] = x :: xs
```

What I want to do is rewrite `prf` using the trivial theorems I have proved until it is exactly the goal but I don't know how to do that in idris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, we need the fact that `::` is injective:

```
consInjective : {x : a} -> {l1, l2 : List a} -> x :: l1 = x :: l2 -> l1 = l2
consInjective Refl = Refl
```

Then we can use the above fact to prove `list_append_eq` by induction on `l`:

```
list_append_eq : (l, l1, l2 : List a) -> l ++ l1 = l ++ l2 -> l1 = l2
list_append_eq [] _ _ prf = prf
list_append_eq (x :: xs) l1 l2 prf =
  list_append_eq xs l1 l2 (consInjective prf)
```

---

Here is a more concise version suggested by @András Kovács, which achieves the same result without `consInjective` by using the standard `cong` (congruence) lemma

```
Idris> :t cong
cong : (a = b) -> f a = f b
```

and the `drop` function:

```
list_append_eq : (l, l1, l2 : List a) -> l ++ l1 = l ++ l2 -> l1 = l2
list_append_eq [] _ _ prf = prf
list_append_eq (x :: xs) l1 l2 prf =
  list_append_eq xs l1 l2 (cong {f = drop 1} prf)
```